# how to get data from text fied mvc 'settings.Properties.TextField' in combobox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, join, combobox

Here is the code of HTML, **i want to get the textField value but the output show the valueField** which i need to put 'ID' in that field. If i change value field to 'BeverageNumber' , the error will show ('Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.') so, the code was successful but **the data doesnt show BeverageNumber, but it show ID number which they get from ValueField.**

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = name;
    settings.Width = width.Value;
    settings.Properties.DropDownWidth = 100;
    settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Foods", Action = "BeverageSide", Width = width, Name = name, Value = value };
    settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
    settings.Properties.TextField = "BeverageNumber";
    settings.Properties.ValueField = "ID";
    settings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0}";
    settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
    settings.Properties.FilterMinLength = 0;
    settings.ShowModelErrors = true;
    settings.Properties.ClientInstanceName = "tFoodRange";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedIndexChanged))
    {
        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = selectedIndexChanged;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lostFocus))
    {
        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.LostFocus = lostFocus;
    }

    settings.Properties.Columns.Add("BeverageNumber", "Beverage Number", 170);
    settings.Properties.Columns.Add("BeverageName", "Title", 300);
})BindList(Restaurant.Shared.Data.GetBeverages, null(ViewData.Eval("Value"))).Bind(value).GetHtml()
```

Here is the C# code

```
public static object GetBeverages(ListEditItemsRequestedByFilterConditionEventArgs args)
    {
        var skip = args.BeginIndex;
        var take = args.EndIndex - args.BeginIndex + 1;

        using (var db = new Restaurant())
        {
            var query = (from beverage in db.BeverageTable
                        join food in db.FoodTable on beverage.ID equals food.BeverageID 

                         where (beverage.IsDeleted == null || beverage.IsDeleted == false) 
                         select new { beverage.BeverageNumber, beverage.ID, beverage.Name, food.Name }).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

            return query;
        }
    }
```

so how i want to get tha data from 'BeverageNumber' which is from TextField and not from 'ID'

Comment: `ComboBox` by default uses `Value` (and `ValueField`) property for model binding. Are you want to get selected `TextField` in another property, or passing `TextField` using same property bound to `ComboBox`?

Comment: yes, i want to  get selected TextField in combobox in another property,

Comment: How about using hidden field to obtain `TextField`? You could handle submit trigger of the form (e.g. button click) to retrieve `TextField` and write it into a hidden field, and make sure that the property is bound to selected `TextField` while the form is submitted. What is the name of property you want to bind with `TextField`?

Comment: do u mean like this?  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Beverage1, new { id = "textBeverageNumber", value = Model.BeverageNumber })

Comment: `value = Model.BeverageNumber` doesn't immediately assign the value, you need to use client-side events to assign `HiddenFor` value with `TextField` from combobox before submit the form. Did you have DevExpress button helper as submit button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188565/discussion-between-much-and-tetsuya-yamamoto).